# How make enter button (keyboard) work properly in forms in IE8?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, internet-explorer, enter

The problem is only happening in Internet Explorer.  In any other browser I can submit the form by hitting enter on my keyboard, in IE8 I have to actually click the button.

I searched around for fixes for a while and found a few things but it's still not working.  The javascript I'm using should be looking for keycode 13, which is enter, but when I hit enter the field clears itself without submitting the form and the keycode is not triggered.  The keycode thing only returns results for letters and not for shift/enter.

Here's the HTML my current solution:

```
    <form action="chatscreen.php" name="loginform" method="post"> 
        <p>Please enter your name to continue:</p> 
        <label for="name">Name:</label> 
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onkeyup="whichButton("loginform","enter")"/> 
        <button type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Enter">Button</button>
    </form>
```

And here's the javascript I tried to implement as a fix:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function whichButton(formname,elementname) {
    alert("got a key = " + event.keyCode);
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    var followingInput = document.getElementById(elementname);
    document.formname.elementname.click();
    }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow great question with all the code and detail.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837803/key-code-check-in-javascript-not-working-for-ie . Hope me , this is helpful for u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function whichButton(formname,elementname) {
       var keyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : keyEvent.keyCode;
       if (keyID === 13) {
          var followingInput = document.getElementById(elementname);
          document.formname.elementname.click();
       }
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple; just set your defaultbutton property

```
 <form id="Form1" defaultbutton="enter" action="chatscreen.php" name="loginform" method="post">
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: defaultbutton doesnt seem to be valid html attribute

Comment: @MichałWereda check this link out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton(v=vs.110).aspx