# Why it doesn't work in IE 6-8 (catching Enter with jQuery)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This code doesn't work in IE 6-8. Why?

```
$(".put").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if ($(this).is(":focus")) {
            $(this).submit().select();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here's the full page https://rawgithub.com/ruslankh/Kurchatovy/master/index.html

Thank you :)

Comment: I don't think keyCode is the right event, try e.which

Comment: Hmm... My guess is that you should warp your inputs into a `<form>` (and by the way making your HTML valid) and then send the form : `$(this).closest('form').submit()`

Comment: who cares if it is valid or not? dont try to fix irrelevant problems

Comment: @BarryChapman well, that was between brackets... Don't be rude

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/837808/1948292

Comment: Your code fails in IE8-, because you're trying to access `$` in that conditional script - and it's not defined yet, as jQuery is loaded in the end of `<body>`.

Comment: Which version of `jQuery` you are using ? Since `jQueury-2x` it dropped supporting `IE-6/7/8`.

Comment: @raina77ow: he knows that, thats the notion of his problem

Comment: No, he doesn't. He even didn't check the console.

Comment: ah, you edited your comment - i see now

Comment: Now, I saw the console and it says `e` is not defined because there is no handler at all.

Comment: @Recovering Since 2003 jquery 1.9.1

Comment: @Recovering Since 2003 now console is crystal clear

Answer (score 1):

Try using **[e.which()](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)** to support all the browsers

```
 var code = e.which;

 if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
        if ($(this).is(":focus")) {
            $(this).submit().select();
        }
        return false;
 }
```

Comment: It's not necessary to check for both `keyCode` and `which`: jQuery patches `Event` object ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)). And in any case that's not the problem at the page shown.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will [normalize the keyCode](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) into **e.which** - so it should be safe to use just e.which.

I'm however unsure about the following code - I'm surprised it works in other browsers than IE6-8.

```
$(this).submit().select()
```

In the context above **$(this)** is the input-element. The submit() function should be called on the **form** element. The input element can not be submitted by itself, the [onsubmit event exists only on the form element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-onsubmit).

As Brewal mentions in his comment, you should find the wrapping form element and submit() the form. Without a form-element your input element has nowhere to post its content.

Answer (score -1):

certain browsers do not support e.keycode see this example

```
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if(keycode == '13'){
    alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox');  
}
```

also if you using or have recently switched to a newer version of jquery ( 2.0+) IE8 and below are no longer supported

also using $(this).submit() inside of your function, is telling the input to submit itself, but inputs do not submit, the form submits.